# jQuery hover issue - last li element stays hoverd

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I was trying so many options, but no results. However, I have this code

```
<ul class="left_nav">
    <li class="left_nav1"><a href="#">opt1</a></li><li class="left_nav2">
    <a href="#">opt1</a></li><li class="left_nav3">
    <a href="#">opt1</a></li><li class="left_nav4">
    <a href="#">opt1</a></li><li class="left_nav5">
    <a href="#">opt1</a></li>
</ul>
```

and these div's with images

```
<div id="news1" class="news">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/news/news1.jpg" width="340" height="255" alt="" title="" /></a>
</div>
<div id="news2" class="news">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/news/news2.jpg" width="340" height="289" alt="" title="" /></a>
</div>
<div id="news3" class="news">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/news/news3.jpg" width="340" height="232" alt="" title="" /></a>
</div>
<div id="news4" class="news">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/news/news4.jpg" width="340" height="250" alt="" title="" /></a>
</div>
<div id="news5" class="news">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/news/news5.jpg" width="340" height="226" alt="" title="" /></a>
</div>
```

Now `class="news"` by default is `display: none;`. With this jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.left_nav li").hover( function() {
            index = $("ul.left_nav li").index(this) + 1;
            $('#news' + index).addClass('active');
        }, function() {
            $('#news' + index).removeClass('active');
        }
    );
});
```

the div's are appering on hover by adding the class `active` which is defined as `display: block;`. I want to remove this class again when the mouse is on the `<ul>` menu. But if the mouse leave the menu, then the last hovered `<li>` stays hovered, and the div with image will stay visible too. How can I realize that?

Thanks!​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind it with mouseover and than make each event clear other news but the mouseovered one.

```
$("ul.left_nav li").mouseover( function () {

     index = $("ul.left_nav li").index(this)+1;

     $('.news').removeClass('active');

     $('#news'+index).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: the line `$('.news').removeClass('active');` would be much more efficient if it read `$('.news.active').removeClass('active');` there could theoretically be hundreds of news items that are not active we do not need to cycle through.

Comment: yep that is a smart fix indeed.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/HcjLW/1/

You'll want to give the hovering divs some sort of unique id so we can translate that to the id (or index) of the divs with the images.

**HTML With IDs instead of classes**

```
    <ul class="left_nav">
        <li id="left_nav1"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
    $("ul.left_nav li").hover( function () {
        $('#news'+  $(this).attr('id').replace('left_nav','')).addClass('active');
    }, function () {
        $('#news'+  $(this).attr('id').replace('left_nav','')).removeClass('active');
    });
```

---

**Cleaner Solution**

---

A better idea is to give all left_nav items a common class, and use the `data-XXXX` attribute to assign an index (`data-index`).

http://jsfiddle.net/HcjLW/3/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="left_nav">
    <li class="left_nav_item" data-index="1"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
    <li class="left_nav_item" data-index="2"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
    <li class="left_nav_item" data-index="3"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
    <li class="left_nav_item" data-index="4"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
    <li class="left_nav_item" data-index="5"><a href="#">opt1</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    $(".left_nav_item").hover( function () {
        $('#news'+  $(this).data('index')).addClass('active');
    }, function () {
        $('#news'+  $(this).data('index')).removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, i understand what do you keep in mind, but you do not understand my question. Now your code is work like i write, when i mouse leave the menu, and active class is remove. He must stay.

Comment: Then just get rid of the line with `removeClass(...)` and it won't be removed when the mouse leaves it.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't include the document's ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.left_nav li").hover( function () {
        index = $("ul.left_nav li").index(this)+1;
        $('#news'+index).addClass('active');
    }, function () {
        $('#news'+index).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

this will work